# How to properly count elements in my object collection

Tags: powershell

I have the following collection;

```
Collection  Property1   Property2
---------------------------------
Coll1       blue        hot
Coll1       red         cold
Coll1       yellow      orange
Coll1       false       false
Coll2       dog         cat
Coll2       out         in
Coll2       house       car
Coll3       yellow      red
Coll3       brick       mortar
Coll3       winter      winter
Coll3       summer      summer
Coll3       ski         snow
Coll3       cyan        brown
```

How do I count how many elements that are in `Coll1` (the number of collections will be dynamic so the filter also has to be)?
I guess I am looking for something like `how many elements has a unique collection ID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen a hashtable in PowerShell that would output as what you have shown in your question, but usually the way is like the following:

```
Get-Foo | Group-Object Collection -NoElement
```

Comment: Thank you! I've created the hashtable with `New-Object PsObject -Property @{}`. Wouldn't it be correct to call this a hashtable? 

And How would I put the results into one displayable variable?

Comment: Just because you pass a hashtable with property names and values to the `-Property` argument doesn't mean that the result is a hash table. What you have shown there is an array of `PSObject`s, each of which shares the same three properties you created. And you can assign the line to a variable, just like you would do any other assignment.